# A problem with the definition of $e^x$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

I am very experienced in the world of calculus, but there is a certain problem I need to solve that I can't quite get my head around. The canonical definition of $e$ is $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$
Therefore, $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}}$$
However, I often see this written as 
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}}$$
Why do these limits have the same value?

Comment: “Limits have the same value” does not necessarily mean “two forms are equivalent”.

Comment: Good point. I edited it. Still, why **do** the limits have the same value?

Comment: Following your setup, if $x$ is an integer, we have: 
$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{x}{nx}\right)^{nx}}$$

Then if $\lim_{k\to\infty}{\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k}$ exists, the above limit must be equal to this one (since it's a sub-sequence).

Comment: Take natural logs of both limits, slide $ln$ inside by continuity, use L'Hopital's rule on each of them, and see that ($ln$ of) both limits come out to $x$.

Comment: @Learning This is precisely the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is better to think of this the other way around. You first treat $e^x$ as purely a notation, and then set

$$e^x := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

which you can then *prove* satisfies the two properties expected of an exponential function, namely that

$$e^0 = 1$$

and

$$e^{x + y} = e^x e^y$$

. Hence, to find its "base", simply set $x = 1$. And thus you *derive* the expression for $e$, and use this to define it, so that the above is now a literal exponentiation.

---

**ADD:** Now I see you want this the "first" way around, which wasn't quite clear from how the question was written (said "a problem with the definition of $\exp$", so thus why I answered it this way).

In that case, we need another definition for exponentiation of a real base to a real exponent. In fact, such a definition - and arguably a more basic and intuitive one to start with - exists: it is this.

> The **exponential** $b^x$ with a positive base $b$ and arbitrary real number $x$, is the unique function which satisfies the following axioms.
>
> 1. $b^0 = 1$.
> 2. For any two real numbers $x$ and $y$, $b^{x + y} = b^x b^y$.
> 3. $b^x$ is continuous in $x$.

In particular, the first two properties effectively fix the values at rational numbers $x$; the third then fixes them at irrational numbers (proof would be for a different answer; but basically it boils down to that what comes out of the first two for rationals only can be thought of as having "an uncountable number of removable singularities", and then we "remove" them all.).

(From a more sophisticated perspective, the exponential maps $x \mapsto b^x$ are the homeomorphism-isomorphisms between the additive topological group of all reals and the multiplicative topological group of positive reals.)

Once we know that a function like this exists, and then define

$$e := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

we then first have a *consequence*

$$e^x = \left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^x$$

. We now have to move the *real* power into the limit. This requires a lemma:

> **Lemma 1.** (Continuity in the *base*) The function $b \mapsto b^x$, with a fixed $x$, is continuous.

(Can try adding a proof but wanna keep this mostly to exposing the theory and not filling out all the technical details.). With that we can exchange the limit out from underneath the power:

$$e^x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^x$$

The next step is the following rule (again, proof omitted).

> **Lemma 2.** For any reals $x$ and $y$ and a given base $b$, $(b^x)^y = b^{xy}$.

From that, we can go to

$$e^x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}$$

Note that this works because the arbitrary real power is defined and continuous in both arguments. We can thus then take the substitution $m := nx$ to get (this follows from the limit rule for a composite of continuous functions):

$$e^x = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{m}{x}}\right)^m = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{m}\right)^m$$

.

Comment: Good answer, but I am kind of interested in doing it the other way around. Any hints? I tried the binomial expansion, but it's a bit of a difficult mess.

Comment: @K.defaoite There isn't another way, really. Part of the problem is that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are actually used to **define** exponentiation over the real numbers. For example, $2^\pi$ doesn't really have a sensible definition except as $\exp(\pi \cdot \ln 2)$. How else could you define it? It's not like we can say it's $2$ multiplied to itself $\pi$ times. So, if you write $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}$, where $x$ is real, you're already implicitly using $\exp$.

Comment: @user797616 - Maybe he's defining it by the binomial expansion, or by a limit of rational exponents.

Comment: @user797616 Personally, I would define $2^{\pi}$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty} {2^{\frac{p_n}{q_n}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} {\sqrt[q_n]{2^{p_n}}}$, where $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is the sequence of rational approximations of $\pi$ which can be found via [continued fractions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedContinuedFraction.html)

Comment: @K.defaoite: if we follow your definition the problem being discussed here is reduced to showing the identity for rational values of $x$. Perhaps you know for rational $x$ this is just a matter of algebra of limits.

Comment: @K.defaoite : Added the "other way around" now. There's 2 lemmas left for you to fill in the details of which is good exercise in elementary Analysis.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I appreciate the in depth answer. The $m=nx$ trick was all I needed actually. Somehow I missed this before.

Comment: +1 for the sections added. Overall a very good outline with key results stated clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, let $m=nx$, so $n=m/x$, and substitute in the limit. Of course, $n\to\infty\iff m\to\infty$.

Comment: I suppose this assumes $x$ is positive, but it seems general enough. Thanks.

Comment: My sloppiness, yes. The negative case follows because $a^{-n} = (a^n)^{-1}$, no?